MySQL GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP, how to force blank values in rollup row?
This is pretty much the same question as this one but I still can't make it work with my data.
I have two tables joined by fee_name.
I'm selecting a fee, performing a group count, doing a calculation and getting a rollup total.
My initial SQL works to get the numerical results I want.
However the rollup row shows the same fee (17.70) as the row above it, which is meaningless as the rollup total doesn't correspond to any fee.
I am trying to get an empty string in the fee column for the roll up row. (similar to the other SO post)
Can anyone show me where I am going wrong and help me with the correct code for my tables?
I have shown three further attempts at getting the SQL right and the results, which still don't give me what I want, including one following advice from here
(Note, those further attempts deliberately show the original fee column and add an extra column with my attempts to get an empty string in that column )
These are my two tables
bmc_fee  - (only has 3 rows)
|fee_name | fee   | 
|Adult    | 23.90 | 
|Student  | 19.75 | 
|U18      | 17.70 | 

bmctypes  - (has about 600 rows)
|fee_name |
|Adult    |
|Adult    |
|Adult    |
|Student  |
|Adult    |
|U18      |
|Student  |
etc...

My initial SQL
SELECT
   IF(GROUPING(bmctypes.fee_name), 'xTotal', bmctypes.fee_name) AS fee_name,
   COUNT(*) AS num,
   bmc_fee.fee, 
   bmc_fee.fee * COUNT(*)  AS expense
FROM  bmctypes 
JOIN bmc_fee 
ON bmc_fee.fee_name  = bmctypes.fee_name
GROUP BY bmctypes.fee_name WITH ROLLUP;

Expected Result (blank in the fee column for the xTotal row)
|fee_name | num | fee   | expense  |
|Adult    | 560 | 23.90 | 13384.00 |
|Student  |   3 | 19.75 |    59.25 |
|U18      |  10 | 17.70 |   177.00 |
|xTotal   | 573 |       | 10142.10 |

My initial results (17.70 in the fee column for the xTotal rollup row)
|fee_name | num | fee   | expense  |
|Adult    | 560 | 23.90 | 13384.00 |
|Student  |   3 | 19.75 |    59.25 |
|U18      |  10 | 17.70 |   177.00 |
|xTotal   | 573 | 17.70 | 10142.10 |

Attempt 2, using IF() and adding an extra column to aid debugging
SELECT
   IF(GROUPING(bmctypes.fee_name), 'xTotal', bmctypes.fee_name) AS fee_name,
   COUNT(*) AS num,
   bmc_fee.fee as fee_1, 
   IF(fee_name ='xTotal','',bmc_fee.fee) AS fee_2,
   bmc_fee.fee * COUNT(*)  AS expense
FROM  bmctypes 
JOIN bmc_fee 
ON bmc_fee.fee_name  = bmctypes.fee_name
GROUP BY bmctypes.fee_name WITH ROLLUP;

Results of attempt 2 with IF()
|fee_name | num | fee_1 | fee_2 | expense  |
|Adult    | 560 | 23.90 | (NULL)| 13384.00 |
|Student  |   3 | 19.75 | (NULL |    59.25 |
|U18      |  10 | 17.70 | (NULL |   177.00 |
|xTotal   | 573 | 17.70 | (NULL)| 10142.10 |

Attempt 3 using a second GROUPING() and adding an extra column to aid debugging
SELECT
   IF(GROUPING(bmctypes.fee_name), 'xTotal', bmctypes.fee_name) AS fee_name,
   COUNT(*) AS num,
   fee as fee_1,  
   IF(GROUPING(fee_name), '', bmc_fee.fee) AS fee_2,
   bmc_fee.fee * COUNT(*)  AS expense
FROM  bmctypes 
JOIN bmc_fee 
ON bmc_fee.fee_name  = bmctypes.fee_name
GROUP BY bmctypes.fee_name WITH ROLLUP;

Results of attempt 3
|fee_name | num | fee_1 | fee_2 | expense  |
|Adult    | 560 | 23.90 | (NULL)| 13384.00 |
|Student  |   3 | 19.75 | (NULL |    59.25 |
|U18      |  10 | 17.70 | (NULL |   177.00 |
|xTotal   | 573 | 17.70 |       | 10142.10 |

And attempt 4, following advice in the SO link
SELECT
   COALESCE(bmctypes.fee_name,'xTotal') AS fee_name,
   COUNT(*) AS num,
   fee as fee_1,  
  (CASE WHEN bmctypes.fee_nameIS NULL THEN NULL ELSE fee END) AS fee_col_2,
   bmc_fee.fee * COUNT(*)  AS expense
FROM  bmctypes 
JOIN bmc_fee 
ON bmc_fee.fee_name  = bmctypes.fee_name
GROUP BY bmctypes.fee_name WITH ROLLUP;

Results with COALESCE and CASE
|fee_name | num | fee_1 | fee_2 | expense  |
|Adult    | 560 | 23.90 | (NULL)| 13384.00 |
|Student  |   3 | 19.75 | (NULL |    59.25 |
|U18      |  10 | 17.70 | (NULL |   177.00 |
|xTotal   | 573 | 17.70 | (NULL)| 10142.10 |


What is the expected result?

I did explain my expected result in my 3rd paragraph but I have now edited my question to explicitly show it

Just my opinion, but I think you should make this two separate SELECT statements,  one for the detail section and one for the total row.  If you want them in the same output, UNION them together.  That will make things a whole lot easier.

The query shown is really only one of several that I execute inside a stored procedure one after the other, many of which create temp tables that further queries use. I ended up with this version of the final query as creating yet another temp table made the whole procedure take 35s to execute instead of a few seconds as now. I could have a go at doing what you suggest but using rollup is a pretty standard method so I would expect there is a simple solution to my dilemma. - I just can't see it!

You mentioned temporary tables as your performance problem, but not a UNION.  Do you have any objection to using the UNION?  Six hundred rows is not a lot of data.

No objection to using UNION. In fact, since the result is used in a report I can simply get the report to blank that cell when there is 'xTotal' in the first column. However, both that and your suggestion just give an alternative method to achieve the visual effect I want. They do not really answer my question. For my own satisfaction I was hoping to learn what I was doing wrong with my code (as opposed to the answer given in my link, which I can't get to work) and how I should do a rollup on linked tables and obtain only values in the rolled up columns and blanks everywhere else.

Here's a solution:
SELECT
   COALESCE(bmc_fee.fee_name, 'xTotal') AS fee_name,
   COUNT(*) AS num,
   IF(GROUPING(bmc_fee.fee_name), NULL, MAX(bmc_fee.fee)) as fee,
   SUM(bmc_fee.fee) AS expense
FROM bmc_fee
JOIN bmctypes ON bmc_fee.fee_name  = bmctypes.fee_name
GROUP BY bmc_fee.fee_name WITH ROLLUP;

Output given your sample data:
+----------+-----+-------+---------+
| fee_name | num | fee   | expense |
+----------+-----+-------+---------+
| Adult    |   4 | 23.90 |   95.60 |
| Student  |   2 | 19.75 |   39.50 |
| U18      |   1 | 17.70 |   17.70 |
| xTotal   |   7 |  NULL |  152.80 |
+----------+-----+-------+---------+

Dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cu5YYscLmhUb6ZYnPUt2Zz/0
In your example desired output, the last line's expense is less than the sum of the expenses of each line. I guess it's because it's calculating the total count against a fee of 17.70, not the real sum. The query solution I show above sums the actual expenses.

Ah, That's almost what I had with my attempt 3 except that I just had bmc_fee.fee and not (max(bmc_fee.fee). In fact I tweaked your DBfiddle and replaced NULL by the empty string '' and got exactly what I was looking for. I also see now where my thinking was going wrong in my attempt 3. That GROUPING() clause expects an aggregated column so using Max() on a single value does the trick. Thank you, answer accepted.
